# Распараллелить программу с помощью OpenMP

Tags: openmp, c

Табулирование функции 1 /(корень 3й степени из x). В input.txt промежуток и шаг, в output.txt результаты. Как можно максимально распараллелить программу?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double function (double x) {
    double a, b;
    a = 0;
    b = x;
    while (1>0) {
        a = 0.5*(b + 3*x / (2*b*b + x/b)); 
        if(((a-b)<=(0.1) && (a-b)>=0) || ((a-b)>(-0.01) && (a-b)<0))
        return a;
        b = a;
        //a = 0.5*(b + 3*x / (2*b*b + x/b)); 
        //if (((a-b)<(0.1) && (a-b)>0) || ((a-b)>(-0.1) && (a-b)<0))
        //return 1/a;
        //a = b;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    FILE *fo;
    f = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
    fo = fopen("output.txt", "wt");
    double a, b, step;
    double i;
    fscanf(f, "%lf", &a);
    fscanf(f, "%lf", &b);
    fscanf(f, "%lf", &step);
    #pragma omp for (i = a; i <= b; i += step) {
        fprintf(fo, "%.14f\n", function(i));
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fo);
}
```

Comment: 1. А у вас это компилируется? `for` залез на строку с `#pragma`.
2. Вам нужно найти количество процессоров (пусть это `N`), разделить множество на значений для табуляции на `N` частей, и вычислить значения каждой части в своём потоке. В файл лучше писать потом, когда вычисления закончены. (Если, конечно, помещается в памяти. Если нет — используйте `N` файлов, потом сольёте вместе.)
3. Задача настолько проста, что можно обойтись и без OpenMP.

Comment: @Vlad, насколько я помню синтаксис OMP, там есть конструкция с for. Я не уверен, что fprintf потокобезопасная функция, и что ею можно писать в файл одновременно.

Comment: @smallFish: вот [тут](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor) пишут так:

    #pragma omp for
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    {
        // ...

---
Я тоже сильно сомневаюсь, что `fprintf` потокобезопасен.

Comment: Там надо писать:

    #pragma omp for
      for (i = ... ) {
         ...
      }

и компилировать, например, `gcc -fopenmp ...`

Без ключа -fopenmp gcc просто игнорирует `#pragma omp`.

Что же касается thread-safe-ли fprintf() или нет (и в какой ОС), это другой уже вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно что по заданию требуется найти именно последовательность, а не ту мешанину которую выдаст распараллеленый for. Записывай результаты в массив (индекс из for возьми), а потом массив в master-потоке или вне параллельной области запиши в файл.